# Correct explanation for generic vectorial, radial and central field

Tags: symmetry, definition, vector-fields

I suppose to have a absolutely general field of the type $\vec{F}(\vec{r})\colon D\subseteq\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ where $|\vec{r} |=\vec{OP}$.

- If I fix the direction of $\vec{r}$, than $\vec{F}(\vec{r})$ is **radial field** when $\vec{F}(\vec{r})=f(\vec{r}) {\bf \hat r} \ $ but $f(\vec{r})$ can depend of an polar angle, azimuthal or other angles, but does not it must not depend from the quantity $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \ ?$$
  Why?
- $\vec{F}(\vec{r})$ is **central field** when $\vec{F}(\vec{r})=f(r) {\bf \hat r} \ $ where $f(r)$ depend only from the distance $r=\mathrm{d}(O,P)=\overline{OP}$?
- Obviously if a field is radial it is also central (spherical symmetry field). Can it be a *central field* but not radial (e.g. a cylinder - cylindrical symmetry -)?

I ask you, with lot of kindness, if the definitions are correct and if further additions or explanations of my old reminders.

Comment: Consider functions $f=r^2$ and $f= r^2 \sin \theta$. What do you conclude?

Comment: @CosmasZachos The first function $f=r^2$ give, for a vectorial field $\mathbf F$, a central field and it is also radial. The second function $f=r^2\sin \theta$ would be radial but not it is central.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I will happy to have from you an courtesy answer. My regards and best wishes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what more you want...

Comment: @CosmasZachos If I could give an answer with a more correct and/or optimal description accompanied also by simple examples. My Christmas wishes.

Comment: With due respect, this is not a trenchant conceptual issue...

Comment: @CosmasZachos But my previous response is it correct after your first comment?

Comment: Yes, how could  it be otherwise?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I wanted to remove all the comments to vote for your answer even if it was concise. That's all.